# Rider saids can not update dotnet core in path “/usr/share/dotnet/dotnet”

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, manjaro

I have been working with dotnet core in manjaro, I have followed the official guide from Microsoft, they recommend you to install donet-sdk and runtime from snap store, but has some drawbacks with manjaro, like, dotnet tools doesn't work properly.

So I uninstalled the snap version, And now I Followed the wikiarch to install dotnet from a script, everything its fine, even the dotnet tools like donet-ef works properly, but when I tried to create a new solution with Rider, but it says
"Rider can not update dotnet core in path '/usr/share/dotnet/dotnet' "

Output of:
`whereis dotnet`
is
`dotnet: /usr/bin/dotnet /usr/share/dotnet`

And the ouput of:
`which dotnet`
is
`/usr/bin/dotnet`

Whats the problem here, When I try to create a new solution or project with the command `dotnet new`works pretty well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my case it helped to close Rider and delete the folders ~/.cache/JetBrains/Rider2021.1 and ~/.config/JetBrains/Rider2021.1
Afterwards Rider provided all .NET Core project options under "New Solution" and successfully loaded existing projects/solutions.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I don't know exactly what I did for make it work, I just create a new solution or project with:

```
dotnet new web -o CliWebApp
```

Then I Force Rider to open the project, and that's it, now when I try to create a new solution, the donet core menu appears like nothing.

[image]